# ASP.NET Web API - call database to insert via async method, but it doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have this method:

```
public async static Task ExecuteSpAndForget(string sp, Location location, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
      using (SqlConnection conn = await GetConnectionAsync(location))
      {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeout"]);

            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
}

public async static Task<SqlConnection> GetConnectionAsync(Location location)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString" + location]);
    await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return conn;
}
```

And in my log filter I applied to `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new LogFilter());
```

And in `LogFilter()`, I call the database to write log

```
public static int WriteLog(HttpActionContext actionContext, Exception exception = null)
{
     \\logic

var logTask = DatabaseHelper.ExecuteSpAndForget("writelogSP", Location.Log, sqlParams.ToArray());
     \\return logic
}
```

When I am debugging locally, this never writes to the database, when I deployed it to IIS, it sometimes write to the database, sometimes not. I tested it locally in a console app, if I wait several seconds after calling before exit, data can be inserted into the database, otherwise no insert happens if no wait.

Why? How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is a background task.

There are different ways of going about it. The simplest one is **Task.Run** with no await

```
public static int WriteLog(HttpActionContext actionContext, Exception exception = null)
{
     \\logic

      // fire and forget, no await
      var logTask = Task.Run(async () =>
      {
            await DatabaseHelper.ExecuteSpAndForget("writelogSP", Location.Log, sqlParams.ToArray());         
       });

    \\return logic;

}
```

You can check out this link https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html for a better solution.